# Definite Integration

Tags: integration

For some constant c, we wish to compute the following integration (or a tighter bound on the same)
$\int_{\theta}^{1}  x  \exp \left(- \frac{c\theta}{x}\right) dx $

Comment: Why? Please edit the question to include additional background and motivation. Also, please include a description of what you have already tried. These things help make the question more compelling, help others find it, and help others write more useful answers.

Comment: What are the ranges of $c$ and $\theta$ ?

Comment: C is a fixed constant with $C>1$, and $\theta$ is a positive real number less than 1.

Comment: You could as well parameterize with $a=c\theta$ and $b=c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\dfrac{c\theta}t$.
Then

$$\int_{\theta}^{1}  x  \exp \left(- \frac{c\theta}{x}\right) dx =-(c\theta)^2\int_{c}^{c\theta} t^{-3} \exp \left(-t\right) dt=(c\theta)^2(\Gamma(-2, c\theta)-\Gamma(-2,c)).$$

Depending on the values of $c$ and $\theta$, you can use some [asymptotic approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Asymptotic_behavior) of $\Gamma$.